# Loop for Responses Keeps Shifting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I was hoping to get a second pair of eyes on a fairly simple portion of my script. This script is triggered every time a response is submitted, and all it does is take a column of data that holds an identifying string of text and turns it into a hyperlink to go and edit that particular response. For some reason though, the hyperlinks refer to the incorrect response. Stranger still, every time a response is submitted, the offset increases by 1. Here's an example:

**ORIGINAL**

- Entry 1 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 1
- Entry 2 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 2
- Entry 3 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 3
- Entry 4 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 4

**AFTER 1 SUBMIT**

- Entry 1 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 2
- Entry 2 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 3
- Entry 3 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 4
- Entry 4 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 1

**AFTER 2 SUBMITS**

- Entry 1 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 3
- Entry 2 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 4
- Entry 3 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 1
- Entry 4 - Hyperlink Goes to Entry 2

And here is the code I am using to generate the hyperlinks:

```
var _sht = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX").getSheetByName("Sheet");
var formID = "YYY";
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
var formResponses = form.getResponses();

for (var ii=0; ii<formResponses.length; ii++) {
  var tradeName = _sht.getRange(ii+2, 2).getValue();
  _sht.getRange(ii+2, 2).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + formResponses[ii].getEditResponseUrl() + '","' + tradeName + '")');
}
```

Comment: How are you getting `formResponses`?

Comment: @KayceBasques Updated to show variable declarations. Thanks

Comment: @Rawrcasm, This is currently working perfectly for me. Have you tried it in isolation in a test form? I'm currently not able to reproduce anything like you describe, it all hyperlinks correctly.

Comment: @HDCerberus Yes - this is currently the only script running when responses are submitted. Fortunately, I've identified the problem. `form.getResponses()` are ordered by timestamp (which updates when edited), whereas in the sheet they are ordered by original submission. I am currently working on incorporating this factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fix, I've basically used a modified version of AD:AM's answer located [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/LSKKCR3VHC8/DVa7kxp-BLYJ). My modifications include adding an additional array to capture the answer to the 2nd question of each response, and using that as the title of the hyperlink. This is to keep the sheet clean - instead of having an additional column with long hyperlinks, it simply replaces the existing data with a hyperlink-enabled version.

```
var tradeCol = 2, timeCol = 4;  
var data = _sht.getDataRange().getValues();
var timestamps = [], urls = [], trades = [], resultUrls = [];

for (var i=0; i<formResponses.length; i++) {
  timestamps.push(formResponses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
  urls.push(formResponses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  trades.push(formResponses[i].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse());
}

for (var j=1; j<data.length; j++) {
  resultUrls.push([
    data[j][timeCol-1]?
    '=HYPERLINK("' + urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][timeCol-1].setMilliseconds(0))] + '","' + trades[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][timeCol-1].setMilliseconds(0))] + '")':
    '']);
}

_sht.getRange(2, tradeCol, resultUrls.length).setFormulas(resultUrls);
```